# How to convert a formatted number to regular number (with no commas or decimals)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that uses the locale module and converts a number into a formatted number with comma separators and decimals

```
def equals(self):
    data = self.e.get()
    data1 = eval(data)
    data1 = locale.format("%.2f", data1, grouping = True)
    self.ans.configure(text = "Answer: " + str(data1))
```

Now I need the reverse: I need a way to convert a formatted number into a regular number with no commas or decimals. I'm using a Mac

Comment: Side comment: does this really have to do with `tkinter`?

Comment: Show an example of what `e.get()` returns. You most likely want to use `float` instead of `eval`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist My application is a calculator so I need eval to evaluate the expressions put into the entry box

Comment: @oezeadi. That would be useful information  to add to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [`locale.atof`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/locale.html#locale.atof).  It was designed for exactly this purpose.  You need to set the locale with `setlocale` first before you use it.

```
In [1]: import locale

In [2]: locale.atof('2,345.50')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-298dfa9db644> in <module>()
----> 1 locale.atof('2,345.50')

/AnacondaPython/Python35/lib/python3.5/locale.py in atof(string, func)
    316 def atof(string, func=float):
    317     "Parses a string as a float according to the locale settings."
--> 318     return func(delocalize(string))
    319 
    320 def atoi(string):

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,345.50'

In [3]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
Out[3]: 'LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8'

In [4]: locale.atof('2,345.50')
Out[4]: 2345.5
```

The benefit of this is that it will work even for international users that use `','` for the decimal point separator and `'.'` for the thousands separator.

Comment: @oezeadi. This is the only answer that will work in any locale. The replace answer is a quick and dirty hack by comparison, that will only really work in  the US. You can always change your selection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way, I am fairly new to python but I can give it a shot.

Have you tried using the replace() function? something like

```
string.replace(",", "")
```

which would remove all of the commas. You could use round() for removing decimals.

Comment: It's a great answer but I accept the other one using locale.atof because it was more efficient and works in any locale. Thank you though!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that by different roads.

You can simply use the `float(data1)` to convert from the formatted number (string) to a regular number (float).

But if you want int, you can simply do `int(float(data1))`.

Or you can simply modify the string removing anything after the ',' by doing `data1[:data1.index(',')]`

Comment: float(data) does  not work: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '23,423,432.00'"

Comment: data1[:data1.index(',')] only returns the first 2 digits. How can I get all the numbers?

Comment: in this case, you have to remove the ',', you can acheive that using  float(a.replace(',','')). The data1[:data1.index(',')] is returning the data1 value until the first ','. In cases that we have a lot of ',' in the string, is better to use replace.